# StumbleUpon badge is not loading on site. Unable to post message to http://www.stumbleupon.com. Recipient has origin --- error

Tags: javascript, ssl, badge

I'm trying to put a StumbleUpon badge on a site in an li element. I took
the code from the StumbleUpon page.

www.stumbleupon.com/badges/

When the page loads, however, there are two errors in the console:

---

1) Unable to post message to www.stumbleupon.com. Recipient has origin ---

2) GET https://badge.stumbleupon.com/badge/embed/5/?url=https%3A%2F%2------%2F---%2F 
renderwidgets.js:167
STMBLPN.processWidgets

---

And in the iframe, there is an error page:

This webpage is not available

The webpage at https://badge.stumbleupon.com/badge/embed/5/?url=https%3A%2F%2F-----.com%2Fcb%2F might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

---

The site is using CodeIgniter and is on https. Could this be an issue? Anyone knows why there is an error here...?

Comment: Part of it is that the https://badge.stumbleupon.com page is sending a cert for https://www.stumbleupon.com, so there's almost certainly some sort of issue there. Also, may I clarify whether the dashes are part of the actual error message, or inserted by you to mask your site URL?

Comment: If you're masking the URL, please use http://example.com instead. That's [what it is there for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a certificate error, it is valid for www.stumbleupon.com and stumbleupon.com, but not for **badge**.stumbleupon.com. However, it works without the subdomain too:

> https://stumbleupon.com/badge/embed/5/?url=https://example.com